Why did I have fast-track access in Heathrow on SAS GO?
I was flying from Heathrow to Copenhagen on SAS GO. When I used the self-service machine to print boarding cards and bag-tags, the machine said that fast track was available when printing the boarding pass. This was a surprise to me, because:

Tickets in SAS GO usually don't come with fast track access.
In the SAS mobile app, the boarding pass does not say fast track in the place where it usually does when travelling on SAS Plus.
The paper tickets do not mention anything about fast track anywhere.
My tier with SAS is member, which is not eligible for fast track. Nor am I near the boundary to a higher status.

However, when I then went to the fast track line for security and scanned my boarding card, the turnstile let me through into the fast track area. The same happened to my husband, who was travelling with me and had not registered a reward program with the flight at all.
What happened?

This has happened to me too, and I suspect it has to do with the risk profile of the traveler (country of citizenship, frequency of travel, age etc.).

Among the possibilities (there may be others of course): (a) it’s just a bug which for once worked out in your favour, (b) they do some “teasing”, they give you an extra service for free, so that if you enjoy it maybe next time you will be willing to pay for that or (c) they had very few people in fast track and way too much without so they rebalanced a bit. I don’t think there’s any way to know for sure.
